# Points in Shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to code this in Latex.

Can you help me please!
[image]

I tried to create a shape embedding a minipage in it with no success. In fact I think this is a bad idea, but I don't know any other way to do it.

EDIT: Add code from comment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm] 
    \node (pp)[draw, diamond, shape aspect=1, rotate=0, minimum size=1]{\begin{minipage}{1cm} 
    \centering \tikz{ \draw (.5,2.6) node[] {.}; %... more points } 
    \end{minipage} }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please provide a fully compilable minimal working example by editing the post ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? Such an example starts with `\documentclass...` and ends with `...\end{document}`. It would help the solvers tremendously!

Comment: My solution looks like that

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
            \node (pp)[draw, diamond, shape aspect=1, rotate=0, minimum size=1]{
                \begin{minipage}{1cm}
                    \centering
                     \tikz{
                     \draw (.5,2.6) node[] {.};
                     %... more points
                     }            
                 \end{minipage}
            };
            
            \end{tikzpicture}

Comment: For the points I would go with the `decorations.shapes` library.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know what I'm answering but this looks like the left part of the picture

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[diamond,draw,minimum size=2cm] (a) at (0,3) {};
\node[draw,minimum height=1.8cm,minimum width=2cm,anchor=west] (b) at ([xshift=1mm]a.center) {};
\draw[thick,dotted] ($(a.north)!0.8!(a.south)!0.3!(a.west)$) arc (-120:-330:4mm) -- ++(5mm,0)
coordinate (c);
\draw[thick,dotted] ([shift={(-4mm,-1mm)}]c)--++(15mm,0) --+(0,5mm) ++(0,-5mm)--+(0,5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I needed, now I just have to figure out how to draw those curly arrows.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you simply draw circles fort the points. Below I have defined `\MyHorizontalPoints` and `\MyVerticalPoints` to allow you to draw as many as desired. The size is controlled via `\PointSize` and the spacing is controlled via `\PointSep` which can be adjusted with `\renewcommand{}{}` as illustrated with the yellow dots:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\PointSep}{7pt}%
\newcommand*{\PointSize}{2pt}%
\newlength{\Shift}%
\newcommand*{\MyHorizontalPoints}[2][]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\Shift}{(\x-1)*\PointSep}%
        \draw [#1] (\Shift,0) circle (\PointSize);
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyVerticalPoints}[2][]{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#2} {%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\Shift}{(\y-1)*\PointSep}%
        \draw [#1] (0,\Shift) circle (\PointSize);
    }%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \MyHorizontalPoints[fill=red]{3}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
        \MyVerticalPoints[fill=blue]{5}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.0cm]
        \renewcommand*{\PointSize}{1.5pt}%
        \renewcommand*{\PointSep}{4.0pt}%
        \MyHorizontalPoints[fill=yellow]{5}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```